# Google Apps Script Internal Error while Attempting to Share

Tags: google-apps-script

[image: Internal Error]

Anyone knows how to get rid of this error? Cant share my app in google apps script.

Comment: This seems like an internal issue. Click **Support** on the top right corner and **Send Feedback** so you can be better assisted.

Comment: Perhaps you should speak with your system admin.